# Switched graphics card, now major problems

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, ati, graphics

I have an old nVidia 9600GT, which I pulled out of my computer dual booting with Windows 7 and 13.04. I then plugged in a HD6670. I didn't think to uninstall drivers in 13.04, so I started my computer up and tried to do it after I have plugged the card in. Big mistake. Windows 7 works fine, but my Ubuntu is a mess.

On booting into Ubuntu, the graphics were very glitchy with colours everywhere and flickering. I could make out my terminal from ctrl-alt-t, and followed the instructions to download and install AMD drivers. Everything went well until I got to the config, which failed. I tried a few solutions posted online, but nothing worked, so now I've swapped my 9600GT back in.

I don't have the official nVidia drivers, but the graphics at least aren't glitchy. However, my desktop has dissappeared, and just my wallpaper is visible. I can launch a terminal, which is how I'm writing this message, but not much else.

I've tried reinstalling ubuntu-desktop, where it merely states the most recent version is already installed. I also tried resetting unity, which gave me the following output:

```
ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated
```

And now I'm stuck. I played around with a few files including xorg which seems to have got me in my current mess. Any help with my situation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How much (and what elements) of http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it have you tried? *You may need to purge the Nvidia drivers.*

Comment: Which parts of that _should_ I be attempting? It didn't boot to a black screen, just a very glitchy screen with the AMD in, and a well displayed screen just with the desktop missing with the nVidia in. Purging the nVidia drivers was the first thing I did from terminal, and I haven't reinstalled them.

Comment: swap back to your amd/ati card, purge your xorg and report changes.  amd/ati makes a bigger bang for the buck card and fixing it is better than scurrying back to a hole in the ground.

Comment: I've only got the 9600GT in since it gives me a clear picture, I do ultimately want to get the AMD running. I purged xorg and now ubuntu won't even start. It get's stuck at the ubuntu startup logo, at 5 full dots.